# Android Azure Offline Sync - Not completing sync

Tags: android, azure, synchronization, azure-mobile-services

I have an android app with Azure Mobile Services and implemented Offline Sync. The app works well but when syncing data it seems not to complete so there is always a few rows on tables which have not synced?

Anyone have any ideas what the problem might be. I believe that on the next try it would finish where it left off or am I wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruce's answer is fine but I used a slightly different method without the need to use fiddler.

I change my connection from this

```
mClient = new MobileServiceClient("[AZUREWEBSITE]", cntxall);
                mClient.setAndroidHttpClientFactory(new MyOkHttpClientFactory());
```

To this

```
mClient = new MobileServiceClient("[AZUREWEBSITE]", cntxall).withFilter(
                        new ServiceFilter() {
                            @Override
                            public ListenableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> handleRequest(ServiceFilterRequest request, NextServiceFilterCallback nextServiceFilter) {
                                // Get the request contents
                                String url = request.getUrl();
                                String content = request.getContent();

                                if (url != null) {
                                    Log.d("Request URL:", url);
                                }

                                if (content != null) {
                                    Log.d("Request Content:", content);
                                }

                                // Execute the next service filter in the chain
                                ListenableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> responseFuture = nextServiceFilter.onNext(request);

                                Futures.addCallback(responseFuture, new FutureCallback<ServiceFilterResponse>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                                        Log.d("Exception:", e.getMessage());
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                                        if (response != null && response.getContent() != null) {
                                            Log.d("Response Content:", response.getContent());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                return responseFuture;
                            }
                        }
                );
```

This is the logging method for Azure connections and shows the request in the log.

Answer (score 0):

> The app works well but when syncing data it seems not to complete so there is always a few rows on tables which have not synced?

I would recommend you use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces when handling the sync operations.

For [Incremental Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync), the request would be as follows:

```
Get https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?$filter=(updatedAt%20ge%20datetimeoffset'2017-11-03T06%3A56%3A44.4590000%2B00%3A00')&$orderby=updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true
```

For opting out of incremental sync, you would retrieve all records without the filter `updatedAt`.

```
Get https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true
```

Note: If there are too many items, the SDK would send multiple requests to pull all items that match your given query from the associated remote table. Also, you need to make sure you specify the `includeDeleted()` in your query.

In summary, you need to make sure that all items could be retrieved via the above requests. Additionally, if the pull operation has pending local updates, then the pull operation would first execute a push operation. So, I assume that you could catch the exception when calling pull operation for handling the conflict resolution.